# How to get option values from second select list?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I have a problem with Mechanize/Ruby.

I can't get the second select list options when I am selecting the first ones. If I understood correctly from Google, there are some Ajax magic there.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'

HOME_URL = 'http://www.parkers.co.uk/'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(HOME_URL)

form = page.forms.first

form.field_with(:name => 'ctl00$contentHolder$topFullWidthContent$ctlManufacturerModelDropdownsNew$ddlManufacturer_Control').options.select.each do |manufacturer|
  p manufacturer.text.strip
    form.field_with(:name => 'ctl00$contentHolder$topFullWidthContent$ctlManufacturerModelDropdownsUsed$ddlModel_Control').options.each do |model|
      p model.text.strip
    end
end
```

I get this output in the console:

```
"Select a manufacturer"
"Select a model"
"Abarth"
"Select a model"
"Alfa Romeo"
"Select a model"
"Aston Martin"
"Select a model"
"Audi"
```

As you can see I am not receiving any models with Mechanize, for example:

"Audi - A4", "Audi - A1", etc.

I have already tried some of the Mechanize special skills, for example, `select`, `tick`, `selected`, `click`, `present?` and so on, but it didn't help a lot.

If you have any ideas/tipslinks, please share them.

Comment: It is unnecessary to `require 'nokogiri'` if you are using Mechanize. It does it for you and, if you need access to the Nokogiri DOM inside Mechanize you can get it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mechanize does not support JavaScript and since the model select box is populated via JavaScript, using the select boxes is not going to work.  However, `http://www.parkers.co.uk/` works fine (though differently) if you disable JavaScript.

Disable JavaScript in your browser while using the site and you'll notice that you get a list of manufacturer links:

[image: manufacturer links]

Once you click on one of the manufacturer links you'll get to a new page with model selects populated.

Comment: Please don't use images to demonstrate the information that would be seen unless it's a UI or graphical problem. Instead, copy a small subset of the text that would be seen and format it in your question appropriately, or simply describe it well. Images in questions are generally so small and distorted they are worthless.